# Catching new bookmark event in firefox and Extending the bookmark popup

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm Developing an Extension for FF.
What I'm trying to do is to catch an event when a new Bookmark is created and then to add aditional controlls to the bookmark popup.
I've searched for a long time for the correct way of doing this without any success.
Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `popupshown` event of [editBookmarkPanel](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.xul#130)

Comment: What I want to do is to make the new bookmark panel be shown at all times I add a bookmark.
It happends when i hit ctrl+d I want it also to be shown when I click the star Icon.
Is there a listener to the onClick event of the star button?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so Iv'e found a solution:

```
/* Override the original browser Click event on the star button */
PlacesStarButton.onClick = function PSB_onClick(aEvent){
    // Ignore clicks on the star while we update its state.
    if (aEvent.button == 0 && !this._pendingStmt) {
        PlacesCommandHook.bookmarkCurrentPage(true);
    }
    // Don't bubble to the textbox, to avoid unwanted selection of the address.
    aEvent.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: And one day somenone rediscovers the same solution and overwrites your onClick handler. Then what?

Comment: I actually do need to override it. Because I'm writing my own bookmark handler.
Otherwise bookmarkCurentPage will be called at any case, no way of preventing that.
I actually want to controll when FF shows the panel, in some cases I want it to be shown after one click rather than two, it's harcoded in the onClick.

Comment: But that way you're vulnerable to another extension that will do the same thing. It would be safer to add a star of your own and just hide the built-in through css. Just a thought.